# Optimal LVM Setup to Keep Adding Space to Single Mountpoint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, lvm, vps

VPS setup is as follows

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                    11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
vda                   253:0    0   60G  0 disk
├─vda1                253:1    0  9.8G  0 part /
└─vda2                253:2    0 50.2G  0 part
  └─VolGroup1-LogVol1 252:0    0 50.2G  0 lvm  /mnt/lvm1
vdb                   253:16   0   10G  0 disk
```

```
Disk /dev/vda: 60 GiB, 64424509440 bytes, 125829120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: XXXXXXXX
.
Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/vda1  *        2048  20482047  20480000  9.8G 83 Linux
/dev/vda2       20482048 125829119 105347072 50.2G 83 Linux
.
Disk /dev/vdb: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
.
Device     Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/vdb1   2048 20969471 20967424  10G Linux filesystem
.
Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup1-LogVol1: 50.2 GiB, 53934555136 bytes, 105340928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

/dev/vdb/ is single block storage volume at initially 10GB size. I will add more space to this block storage later. Or could add more block storage (/dev/vdc, /dev/vdc, etc).

I need to mount it to /mnt/lvm1. The applications using this folder will need more an more space and I can't make them use multiple folders.

**What is the optimal setup to keep adding space to a single mountpoint**? Of course I can extend *VolGroup1-LogVol1* onto /dev/vdb1, but **are there other ways to do this which might be easier to manage? This could be in the form of a different PV/VG/LV setup and/or using multiple block storages.**

Comment: Two issues: you should block-format the command outputs so that line breaks are preserved, otherwise it's basically unreadable. And when asking for optimal solutions you need to specify what you want to optimize for: ease of use, performance, reliability? Your last paragraph indicates that it might be ease of use. Opinions on that will vary wildly...

Comment: forgot about block format! Optimize for ease of use and reliability if possible. AFAIK for performance it make little difference in this case. thx.